# Importing from keras module throws exception

Tags: python, keras

Attempting to follow this tutorial:
http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/

I'm running the Anaconda distribution of Python 3.5.3 on CentOs 6.9
and using the Spyder 3.2.0 environment.

Attempting to import from the keras module using
results in the following error:

```
from keras.models import Sequential

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-490b9437d5d1>", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import applications
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/applications/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .vgg16 import VGG16
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/applications/vgg16.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..models import Model
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import layers as layer_module
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..engine import Layer
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .training import Model
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .. import callbacks as cbks
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 19, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import certs
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/certs.py", line 17, in <module>
    from certifi import where
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 954, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 892, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 873, in _find_spec_legacy
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py", line 258, in find_module
    fp, pathname, (ext,mode,ty) = imp.find_module(fullname,package_path)
  File "/home/user1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 279, in find_module
    "not {}".format(type(path)))
RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'
```

Comment: What is your backend insallation? `TensorFlow` or `Keras`?

Comment: Backend is TensorFlow

Comment: your question says 3.6, but your traceback says 3.5 ...

Comment: True story -- it's Python 3.5.3, op has been updated...